# Oracle Recursive Lag Function

Tags: sql, oracle, recursive-query

I have data like this:

```
MON   MONTH_NUM  OPEN_AT_BEG  OPENED  CLOSED
Jan   1          34           19      21
Feb   2          (null)       12      12
Mar   3          (null)       10      8 
Apr   4          (null)       (null)  (null)
May   5          (null)       (null)  (null)
Jun   6          (null)       (null)  (null)
```

This data was created with this code:

```
select 'Jan' mon, 1 month_num, 34 open_at_beg, 19 opened, 21 closed from dual
union select 'Feb', 2 month_num, null open_at_beg, 12 opened, 12 closed from dual
union select 'Mar', 3 month_num, null open_at_beg, 10 opened, 8 closed from dual
union select 'Apr', 4 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
union select 'May', 5 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
union select 'Jun', 6 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
order by month_num
```

I want to do one thing:

- Create a new column `NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG` (`NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG` = Previous Month `OPEN_AT_BEG` + Previous Month `OPENED` - Previous Month `CLOSED`)

The final result should look like this:

```
MON   MONTH_NUM  OPEN_AT_BEG  OPENED  CLOSED  NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG
Jan   1          34           19      21      34               
Feb   2          (null)       12      12      32               
Mar   3          (null)       10      8       32              
Apr   4          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)           
May   5          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)           
Jun   6          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)
```

This result is based on today being April, so everything is filled out up to the previous month (March).

I tried this...

```
with test as (
select 'Jan' mon, 1 month_num, 34 open_at_beg, 19 opened, 21 closed from dual
union select 'Feb', 2 month_num, null open_at_beg, 12 opened, 12 closed from dual
union select 'Mar', 3 month_num, null open_at_beg, 10 opened, 8 closed from dual
union select 'Apr', 4 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
union select 'May', 5 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
union select 'Jun', 6 month_num, null open_at_beg, null opened, null closed from dual
order by month_num
)

select test.*, 
       case when month_num = 1 then open_at_beg 
            else lag(open_at_beg + opened - closed,1,0) over(order by month_num) 
       end new_open_at_beg
from test
order by month_num
```

which resulted in this...

```
MON   MONTH_NUM  OPEN_AT_BEG  OPENED  CLOSED  NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG
Jan   1          34           19      21      34
Feb   2          (null)       12      12      32
Mar   3          (null)       10      8       (null)
Apr   4          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)
May   5          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)
Jun   6          (null)       (null)  (null)  (null)
```

It correctly identified the `NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG` number for February as 32. However, March is `null` for `NEW_OPEN_AT_BEG`, because the lag function is not recursive.

How do I write a recursive lag function to grab previous month data and use in calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want cumulative sums:

```
select t.*,
       (case when open_at_beg is not null then open_at_beg
             when closed is not null and opened is not null
             then (sum(open_at_beg) over () +
                   sum(opened - closed) over (order by month_num rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
                  )
        end) as new_open_at_beg
from test t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c8612e648606914a960aaa09eb47866c) is a db<>fiddle.